# Running old script in new UFT version

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft, hp-alm

I upgrade ALM and UFT to the latest version. There is no GUI change, but when i run the old script it shows this error:

> The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object
> 'TestData$'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name
> and the path name correctly.
>
> Function file: [ALM\Resources]
> Resources\CRAFT Framework\Reusable
> Libraries\Framework_Utilities\ExcelDataAccess.vbs Line (76): "objTestData.Open strQuery, m_objConn".

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to query a worksheet in an excel file that doesn't exist... Check your excel file contains a worksheet called `TestData`

Comment: Check the path in the connection string that is passed to m_objConn object. That path may not exist or that sheet TestData$ may have been removed or renamed.

Comment: Thanks! @ Dave and @ Mithilesh

Comment: @ Dave i am using hybrid frame work ,and the script is old. i am trying to run this old script in new environment. There is no change in functionality, but the developers used upgraded version of .NET. I am not sure where to find TestDta and not also able to change new test server in UFT.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the parameter values in ALM to know the location of excel sheet.